# Silex & phpunit JSON response

Tags: json, phpunit, silex

I am trying to write some tests for Silex using phpunit.

I have a class Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client that generates a Crawler object.

This object expects the results of the client to be xhtml however my api that I am trying to test returns JSON and the crawler does not allow this.

Is there a built in class in either Silex or phpunit that will work with JSON or will I have to roll my own?

Cheers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is nothing special for dealing with json, but you can use the client without using the crawler. Simply call `getResponse()` on the client to get the response, like this:

```
$client = $this->createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/');
$response = $client->getResponse();

$data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
$this->assertSame(array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'igorw'), $data['users'][0]);
```

I suggest you move this logic into a helper method on the test case and use that.

Answer (score 0):

For sending an JSON request in Symfony 2 Browser-Kit use `HTTP_ACCEPT` instead of `ACCEPT` and `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` instead of `CONTENT_TYPE`. Here is an example for sending `POST` request with some `$data`:

```
$client->request(
    $method = 'POST',
    $uri,
    $parameters = array(),
    $files = array(),
    $server = array(
        'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', // for sending urlencoded data
        //or 'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', // for sending JSON data
        'HTTP_ACCEPT'       => 'application/json',      
    ),
    $content = $data,
    $changeHistory = true
);

$response = $client->getResponse();
$response_data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
```